# Choosing a suitable plaintext_modulus

Tags: seal

In choosing parameters such as `plaintext_modulus`, is there any good strategy? (aside from guess-and-check until the output looks correct)

In particular, I'm experimenting with `IntegerEncoder` with BFV. My (potentially-wrong) understanding is that the `plaintext_modulus` is **not** the modulus for the integer being encoded, but the modulus for each coefficient in the polynomial representation.

With B=2, it looks like these coefficients will just be 0 or 1. However, after operations like add and multiply are applied, this clearly is no longer the case. Is there a good way to determine a good bound for the coefficients, in order to pick `plaintext_modulus`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My (potentially-wrong) understanding is that the plaintext_modulus is not the modulus for the integer being encoded, but the modulus for each coefficient in the polynomial representation.

This is the correct way of thinking when using `IntegerEncoder`. Note, however, that when using `BatchEncoder` (`PolyCRTBuilder` in SEAL 2.*) the situation is exactly the opposite: each slot in the plaintext vector is an integer modulo `poly_modulus`.

> With B=2, it looks like these coefficients will just be 0 or 1. However, after operations like add and multiply are applied, this clearly is no longer the case. Is there a good way to determine a good bound for the coefficients, in order to pick plaintext_modulus?

The whole point of `IntegerEncoder` is that fresh encodings have as small coefficients as possible, delaying `plain_modulus` overflow and allowing you to use smaller `plain_modulus` (implies smaller noise growth). SEAL 2.* had an automatic parameter selection tool that performed heuristic upper bound estimates on noise growth and plaintext coefficient growth, and basically did exactly what you want. Unfortunately these estimates were performed on a per-operation basis, causing overestimates in the earlier operations to blow up in later stages of the computation. As a result, the estimates were not very tight for more than the simplest computations and in many cases the parameters this tool provided were oversized.

To estimate the plaintext coefficient growth in multiplications, let's consider two polynomials p(x) and q(x). Obviously the product will have degree exactly equal to deg(p)+deg(q)---that part is easy. If |P| denotes the infinity norm of a polynomial P (absolute value of largest coefficient), then:

|p*q| <= min{deg(p)+1, deg(q)+1} * |p||q|.

Actually, SEAL 2.* is a little bit more precise here. Instead of using the degrees, it uses the number of non-zero coefficients in these polynomials. This makes a big difference when the polynomials are sparse, in which case the contribution from cross-terms is much smaller and a better bound is:

|p*q| <= min{#(non_zero_coeffs(p)), #(non_zero_coeffs(q))} * |p||q|.

A deeper analysis of coefficient growth in `IntegerEncoder`-like encoders is done in https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/250 by Costache *et al.*, which you may want to look at.